# Listar dias da semana, tendo o mês e o ano PHP

Tags: php, data

Estou querendo imprimir os dias da semana separados pela número da semana de determinado mês: O que tenho até agora é:

```
function days_week($date = NULL){

$date = ($date == NULL) ? date('m/d/Y') : $date;
$ts = strtotime($date);
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);

$return = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= 6; ++$i) {
    $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);

    $week_month = date('w', strtotime($ts));
    $return[$week_month][$i]['day_week'] = date("d/m/Y", $ts);
    //echo $return['day_week'];
    switch(date("l", $ts)){
        case 'Sunday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "domingo";
        break;
        case 'Monday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "segunda";
        break;
        case 'Tuesday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "terça";
        break;
        case 'Wednesday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "quarta";
        break;
        case 'Thursday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "quinta";
        break;
        case 'Friday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "sexta";
        break;
        case 'Saturday':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['day_name'] = "sábado";
        break;
    };
    //echo " - ".$return['day_name'];
    switch(date("M", $ts)){
        case 'Jan':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'janeiro';
        break;
        case 'Feb':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'fevereiro';
        break;
        case 'Mar':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'março';
        break;
        case 'Apr':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'abril';
        break;
        case 'May':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'maio';
        break;
        case 'Jun':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'junho';
        break;
        case 'Jul':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'julho';
        break;
        case 'Aug':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'agosto';
        break;
        case 'Sep':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'setembro';
        break;
        case 'Oct':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'outubro';
        break;
        case 'Nov':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'novembro';
        break;
        case 'Dec':
            $return[$week_month][$i]['month_name'] = 'dezembro';
        break;
    }
}
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

Usando:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(days_week("04/01/2018"));
echo "</pre>";
```

Retorna o seguinte:

```
{
"4": [
      {
        "day_week": "25/03/2018",
        "day_name": "domingo",
        "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "26/03/2018",
         "day_name": "segunda",
         "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "27/03/2018",
         "day_name": "terça",
         "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "28/03/2018",
         "day_name": "quarta",
         "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "29/03/2018",
         "day_name": "quinta",
         "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "30/03/2018",
         "day_name": "sexta",
         "month_name": "março"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "31/03/2018",
         "day_name": "sábado",
         "month_name": "março"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Mas dá pra ver que o resultado é errado, porque ele mostra o resultado até dia 31/03, quando era pra mostrar do dia 01/04 em diante... estranho que com os outros dias funciona normal... alguém tem alguma dica? Grato!

---

Objetivo que eu desejo é um JSON deste formato:

ENTRADA DO USUÁRIO

MES: 04
ANO: 2018

SAÍDA (JSON):

```
{
"1": [
      {
        "day_week": "01/04/2018",
        "day_name": "domingo",
        "month_name": "abril"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "02/04/2018",
         "day_name": "segunda",
         "month_name": "abril"
      },
      {
         "day_week": "03/04/2018",
         "day_name": "terça",
         "month_name": "abril"
      },
      ...
      ...
      {
         "day_week": "07/04/2018",
         "day_name": "sabado",
         "month_name": "abril"
      }
     ],
    "2": [
          {
             "day_week": "08/04/2018",
             "day_name": "domingo",
             "month_name": "abril"
          },
          {
             "day_week": "09/04/2018",
             "day_name": "segunda",
             "month_name": "abril"
          },
           ...................
```

Peço perdão aos amigos pois realmente não tinha ficado "entendível" =)
Creio que agora tenha dado para entender, o 1, 2 ... é o número da semana no mês. E preciso da lista dos dias, como descrito no JSON

Comment: Não deu para perceber o objetivo...
É para fazer os sete dias incluindo o dia inserido?
Quantos dias sao suposto retornar?

Tens de ser mais especifico no teu objetivo

Comment: Como o @PedroMartins disse, é preciso ser mais específico no que quer apresentar... contextualize e indique o objetivo por favor.

Comment: Arrumei @PedroMartins e Fernando, grato

Comment: @Hermus me avisa se tiver algum erro ok? Abraço!

Comment: @Hermus você teria algum comentário para fazer sobre minha resposta? Você conseguiu testa-la?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho estava viajando, desculpa pela demora, ficou show, não era exatamente o que eu pensava, mas supriu minha necessidade. Grato

Comment: @Hermus se precisar de mais alguma ajuda, me avise aqui. Abraço!

Comment: @Hermus se tiver que alterar alguma coisa eu ajudo vc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ERROS IDENTIFICADOS NO SEU CÓDIGO**

1. Como mostrado por você no resultado desejado, com a entrada
   do dia `01/04/2018` você gostaria que fossem apresentados as datas
   de um total de 5 semanas(no mês de Abril). Porém no seu código você tem um loop de no
   máximo 7 dias, ou seja, apenas 1 semana no resultado. Por isso troquei o seu `for` por um `while(true)`. Esse 'while' é quebrado assim que o mês termina.
2. Outro erro diz respeito a formatação do `timestamp`. Quando eu disse
   que não identifiquei o erro, na verdade eu não entendi realmente
   porque isso acontece. Mas sei que ele existe e vou mostra-lo a
   seguir.

Primeiro você transforma a data em `timestamp`:

```
$date = "04/01/2018";
$ts = strtotime($date);
```

O Valor retornado é `1522533600`
Depois você resgata o ano e a semana no ano:

```
$year = date('o', $ts); // isso aqui retorna o ano. OK! (2018)
$week = date('W', $ts); // isso retorna o numero da semana no ano. OK! (13)
```

Dentro do loop você tenta usar o seguinte código:

```
$ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
```

Que retorna o valor de `1521932400`. Que é diferente do valor do primeiro dia `1522533600`. Se converter esse valor:

```
// $i = 0
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i));
```

Você terá a data de `25/03/2018`. Exatamente o valor errado do `json`.

Criei uma alternativa para chegar no resultado. Veja:

```
$dia = "01";
$mes = "04";
$ano = "2018";
$data = $dia."-".$mes."-".$ano;

$dia_da_semana_array = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terca', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado'); // lista
$meses_array = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'); // lista
$dia_da_semana_inicial = date('w', strtotime($data)); // pega o dia da semana em inteiro
$dia_da_semana_inicial_string = $dia_da_semana_array[$dia_da_semana_inicial];  // pega o dia da semana  em string

$arraySemanas = array(); // lista das semanas

$x = (int)$dia_da_semana_inicial;
$y = 0;

$semana = 1;
while(true){

    // insere no array
    $indexMes = (int)$mes;
    $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['day_week'] = $data; 
    $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['day_name'] = $dia_da_semana_array[$x];
    $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['month_name'] = $meses_array[$indexMes];

    // verifica se mudou o mês
    $data = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($data)));
    $dataVerifi = explode("-", $data);
    if($dataVerifi[1] != $mes){
        // se mudou o mes para o loop
        break;
    }

    if($x == 6){
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        $semana++;
    } else {
        $x++;
        $y++;
    }

}

print_r(json_encode($arraySemanas));
```

Veja funcionando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/0Qodtx)**

Sua função ficaria assim:

```
function days_week($date = NULL){

    $date = ($date == NULL) ? date('d/m/Y') : $date;

    $date = explode("/", $date);
    $dia = $date[0];
    $mes = $date[1];
    $ano = $date[2];
    $data = $dia."-".$mes."-".$ano;


    $dia_da_semana_array = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terca', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado'); // lista
    $meses_array = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'); // lista
    $dia_da_semana_inicial = date('w', strtotime($data)); // pega o dia da semana em inteiro
    $dia_da_semana_inicial_string = $dia_da_semana_array[$dia_da_semana_inicial];  // pega o dia da semana  em string

    $arraySemanas = array(); // lista das semanas

    $x = $dia_da_semana_inicial;
    $y = 0;

    $semana = 1;
    while(true){

        // insere no array
        $indexMes = (int)$mes;
        $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['day_week'] = str_replace("-","/",$data); 
        $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['day_name'] = $dia_da_semana_array[$x];
        $arraySemanas[$semana][$y]['month_name'] = $meses_array[$indexMes];

        // verifica se mudou o mês
        $data = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($data)));
        $dataVerifi = explode("-", $data);
        if($dataVerifi[1] != $mes){
            // se mudou o mes para o loop
            break;
        }

        if($x == 6){
            $x = 0;
            $y = 0;
            $semana++;
        } else {
            $x++;
            $y++;
        }

    }

    return json_encode($arraySemanas);
}

echo days_week("01/04/2018");
```

Espero que isso te ajude.

Comment: como faz para listar apenas a semana da data informada? exemplo dia dia 01/04/2018, ele retorna apenas o dias do dia 01 ao dia 07.

Comment: @FernandaMaria você pode usar o `date('w', strtotime('01/04/2018'))`. Essa função vai te retornar um inteiro de 0 a 6... 0 = 'domingo' e 6 = 'sabado' ... sabendo o dia da semana que a data se encontra, você pode usar `DateTime` para ir adicionando ou subtraindo datas. Exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564182/9303032

Comment: @FernandaMaria criei um exemplo no ideone https://ideone.com/qyAkZp

Comment: muito obrigada :)